# How should I invest $10,000 in crypto-currency?

Tags: mining-profitability, trading

I have $10,000 which I have decided to invest in crypto-currency.

How should I go about investing this money for maximum profit? E.g. should I invest in a mining setup? Trade the currency? A combination of both?

A few investment parameters and some background on myself is provided below:

- Risk sensitivity would be very high. Although I wouldn't want to be stupid with how I go about investing the money either.
- I am a technically minded person (I am a mechanical and software engineer and I develop progressive web applications for a job and build computer hardware systems as a hobby).
- I would be okay with constructing and maintaining rigs. Although I don't know what coins to mine but I have a basic idea on how to mine them using either ASIC hardware or graphics cards with off the shelf software.
- I wouldn't say I have an investment style. I have never really invested in anything before beside putting my money in high interest bank accounts.

Comment: What is your risk sensitivity? Are you okay if you lost all of this money? Crypto is highly volatile and as such a very speculative investment.

Comment: Are you technically minded and okay constructing and maintaining mining rigs? Do you know what coins to mine and how to mine them? If not, then moving the money into crypto through the buying of coins might be a better approach. If you do buy coins, what is you investment style? Are you a buy/hold type of person? Day-trader? Swing-trader?

Comment: @AR71 Risk sensitivity would be very high. Although I wouldn't want to be stupid with how I go about investing the money either. As for being technically minded I am a mechanical and software engineer and I develop progressive web applications for a job and build computer hardware systems as a hobby.

Comment: @AR71 I would be okay with constructing and maintaining rigs. I don't know what coins to mine. I have a basic idea on how to mine them using either ASIC hardware or graphics cards with off the shelf software. I wouldn't say I have an investment style. I have never really invested in anything before beside putting my money in high interest bank accounts.

Comment: Mining sounds like a good option. There are a few ways to do it. GPU or ASIC. The common ASIC miners (Antminer) are 220v, so you would have to get an electrician in if you are in the US. Each runs in the 800-1000W range, kick out a lot of heat and are a little noisy (70-75 db). There are a lot of websites that tell you how profitable certain coins are. If you Google "crypto mining calculator" there will be a few sites. I use Coinwarz. They list all the algorithms used in mining. Not all algorithms are minable with ASIC miners. They are set to a specific algorithms so you lose some flexibility.

Comment: GPU miners are more expensive, but you can build them yourself and they have the flexibility to mine all coins and all algorithms, so you can go after more obscure ones.

Comment: If you wanted to buy coins, I'd recommend that you don't rush to buy. Move the money into an account like Coinbase. Then wait. Watch the blue-chip coins like BTC, LTC, ETH and wait for a dip of 20-30%. Then buy the dips and hold. If you did something like 50% BTC, 40% LTC/ETH and 10% speculative small coins or ICO it might be as close as possible to being 'conservative'. Obviously, I'm not an advisor so what I know wouldn't cover the back of a matchbox! :-)

Comment: Fact you are asking question means you should not. There is learning curve to have it replied and in different ways. Read and find your personal answer.

Comment: Requests for investment advice are off-topic.

Comment: @Murch I actually initially posted this question on https://money.stackexchange.com/ however the moderator told me to move it here. Where should I post a question like this if not on the finance or crypto currency sub domains?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't know why they told you to move it here. Questions about investing are subjective and outdate quickly, which doesn't match well what we're trying to do with the rest of the site. We've been considering requests for investment advice to be off-topic for a number of years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume Bitcoin since that is by far the most common cryptocurrency by mindshare for people who are new to the space.

Since you have $10k to invest, you could buy around 5 to 7 bitcoin mining rigs with a capacity of 13 to 16 tera-hashes per second each.  Investing in these mining rigs will give you about 1 year of mining time before the rigs cost more money to run than they can make.  You could make approximately $10,000 to $30,000 profit during that time assuming you have cheap electricity, and buy 5 x 15 TH/sec bitminers.  This path requires far more technical knowledge than a simple purchase of  bitcoin.  To get 5 mining rigs for $10k, you'll need to buy direct from a manufacturer.  Bitcoin mining rig manufacturers typically require a wait of 3 or 4 months until delivery.

If you buy bitcoin, you might lose the entire investment if bitcoin goes to zero; on the other hand you might make 10 times your investment if bitcoin repeats the past 12 months of performance.  If you stay invested for a longer timeframe that risk/return is extended.

There is no simple answer to your question since it depends on your technical knowledge, risk appetite, and timeline.